# How to create a custom adapter for a listview? Getting RessourceNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I am trying to make a custom adapter for my listview, but I keep getting a RessourceNotFoundException on the same line.

Firstly, here is my adapter class code:

```
public class CreateProgramAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<TrainingPass> trainingPasses;
    private List<TrainingPass> items;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private Context context;

    public CreateProgramAdapter(Context context, List<TrainingPass> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        TrainingPassHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_createprogram_trainingpasses_item, null);
            holder = new TrainingPassHolder();
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (TrainingPassHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.trainingPass = this.items.get(position);
        holder.trainingPassRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_item_relativelayout);
        holder.headlineTxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_headline);
        holder.setNoTxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_trainingpass_setno);
        holder.showHideIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_showhide_imageview);
        holder.exerciseSearchField = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_exercise_searchfield);
        holder.repsTextField = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_reps_txtfield);
        holder.addSetButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.add_set_button);
        holder.addExerciseButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_addexercise_button);
        holder.setsListView = (ListView) row.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_sets_listview);
        holder.exercisesListView = (ListView) row.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_exercises_listview);

        holder.trainingPassRelativeLayout.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
        holder.headlineTxt.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
        holder.setNoTxt.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
        holder.showHideIcon.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
        holder.exerciseSearchField.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
        holder.repsTextField.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
        holder.addSetButton.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
        holder.addExerciseButton.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
        holder.setsListView.setTag(holder.trainingPass);
        holder.exercisesListView.setTag(holder.trainingPass);

        setupItems(holder);

        return convertView;
    }

    private void setupItems(TrainingPassHolder trainingPassHolder) {
        // TODO: set default values for items

    }

    public static class TrainingPassHolder {
        TrainingPass    trainingPass;
        RelativeLayout  trainingPassRelativeLayout;
        TextView        headlineTxt;
        TextView        setNoTxt;
        ImageView       showHideIcon;
        EditText        exerciseSearchField;
        EditText        repsTextField;
        Button          addSetButton;
        Button          addExerciseButton;
        ListView        setsListView;
        ListView        exercisesListView;
    }
}
```

And here is the xml for the view, containing the listview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mobileplatformexam.activities.CreateProgramActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutCreateProgram">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add training pass"
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass_help"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass_help"
        android:onClick="addTrainingPass"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="\?"
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass_help"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="addTrainingPassHelp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create program"
        android:id="@+id/btn_create_program"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass_help"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass_help"
        android:onClick="createProgram"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView_trainingpasses"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_create_program"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And the xml file with the item layout for the above listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_item_relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Trainingpass"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/trainingpass_showhide_imageview"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/trainingpass_showhide_imageview"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trainingpass_showhide_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/trainingpass_headline" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/trainingpass_showhide_imageview"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trainingpass_showhide_imageview"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:hint="Name of exercise"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_trainingpass_setno"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set 1"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/trainingpass_reps_txtfield"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/trainingpass_reps_txtfield" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/trainingpass_reps_txtfield"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Reps"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:width="160dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_trainingpass_setno"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add_set_button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/add_set_button"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/add_set_button"
            android:text="Add set"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/trainingpass_reps_txtfield"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_trainingpass_setno" />

        <Button
            android:text="Add exercise"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/trainingpass_addexercise_button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/add_set_button"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/add_set_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/trainingpass_exercises_listview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_addexercise_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trainingpass_addexercise_button"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trainingpass_addexercise_button" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code for setting the adapter in my activity (extends Activity)

```
 ArrayList<TrainingPass> trainingPasses = new ArrayList<TrainingPass>();

        TrainingPass trainingPass = new TrainingPass();
        trainingPass.setTrainingPassName("wefwef");

        TrainingPass trainingPass2 = new TrainingPass();
        trainingPass.setTrainingPassName("rwefhtr");

        trainingPasses.add(trainingPass);
        trainingPasses.add(trainingPass2);

        ListView trainingPassesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_trainingpasses);
        CreateProgramAdapter createProgramAdapter = new CreateProgramAdapter(CreateProgramActivity.this, trainingPasses);
        trainingPassesListView.setAdapter(createProgramAdapter);
```

The error i am getting is this:

> 12661-12661/com.mobileplatformexam E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04001a
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1019)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2107)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:858)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
>               at com.mobileplatformexam.Adapters.CreateProgramAdapter.getView(CreateProgramAdapter.java:56)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2466)
>               at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
>               at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12807)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:642)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:424)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12807)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12807)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>               at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12807)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12807)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:690)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:583)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12807)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2218)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12807)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1068)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2452)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

The error refers to line 56 in my adapterclass, which is the following line:

```
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_createprogram_trainingpasses_item, null);
```

I really can't seem to find out what may be wrong with the code, so I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Change  `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_createprogram_trainingpasses_item, null);` to  `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_createprogram_trainingpasses_item, parent , false);`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I am still getting the exact same error.

Comment: In which directory you have "adapter_createprogram_trainingpasses_item.xml" ?

Comment: The adapter_createprogram_trainingpasses_item.xml is currently in the same directory as the rest of the layout xml files.

Comment: initialize your views in this condition `if(convertView==null)`.

Comment: If you use Eclipse, try "Clean & re-build" the project

Comment: @Piyush Gupta I tried it, but i didn't make any difference.

Comment: @JafarKhQ Tried that too, still the same error :( And I am using Android Studio

Comment: Go to "setupItems()" method and make sure you dont set any textView.setText(int) with a number like this textView.setText(6) if just add textView.setText(6 + "")

Comment: the setupItems() doesn't do anything at all yet ..

Comment: Try this. Remove all "holder.xxxx" code. and make sure sure the "adapter_createprogram_trainingpasses_item.xml" is in the "layout" directory not "layout-land" for example

Comment: It is not in "layout-land" or anything else. It is in layout directory. Tried removing all holder.xxx code, but still the same error.
By the way, the Resource ID #0x7f04001a from the error refers to adapter_createprogram_trainingpasses_item in R.java. Just if this should be relevant somehow.

Comment: Last try. to to your item layout and try to simplify it by removing all textCorlor/bgColor ..., or even remove the layout children (TextView Buttons listView ??) just keep on the FreamLyout

Comment: I tried removing everything but the LinearLayout, but still didn't work.. but then I tried using a completely different xml layout, containing only a textview (no linearlayout or anything) for the items.. now I didn't get any errors. How can this be? I don't see what's wrong with the linearlayout in the adapter_createprogram_trainingpasses_item. But something in the top of this file is causing the error

Comment: Never mind, I found out. But thanks a lot for your help @JafarKhQ. I really appreciate it!
You didn't post an answer with the solution so I'll do this myself so others will be able to see how the xml layout should look. I have upvoted your comment though-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JafarKhQ, I solved the problem. 
By changing the layout "adapter_createprogram_trainingpasses_item .xml" to the following, it worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Trainingpass"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/trainingpass_showhide_imageview"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/trainingpass_showhide_imageview"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_showhide_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/trainingpass_headline" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/trainingpass_showhide_imageview"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trainingpass_showhide_imageview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="Name of exercise"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_trainingpass_setno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set 1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/trainingpass_reps_txtfield"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/trainingpass_reps_txtfield" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_reps_txtfield"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Reps"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:width="160dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_trainingpass_setno"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add_set_button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/add_set_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add_set_button"
        android:text="Add set"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/trainingpass_reps_txtfield"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_trainingpass_setno" />

    <Button
        android:text="Add exercise"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_addexercise_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/add_set_button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/add_set_button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_exercises_listview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_addexercise_button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trainingpass_addexercise_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trainingpass_addexercise_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```